# Calling static method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to call a static method of a class from a different module and getting:

`AttributeError: ClassObject instance has no attribute 'foo1'`

Things are structures like this:
`a.py` file content:

```
class Conf():
    def __init__(self,......):
       .
       .
       .
    @staticmethod
    def foo1():
       .
       .
       .
```

`b.py` file content:

```
from a import Conf
Conf.foo1()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's the same thing, I wanted to write here the minimal code necessary to demonstrate it

Comment: I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem, but since this question is tagged with Python 2, try to inherit from `object`: `class Conf(object):`

Comment: Well I will try now

Comment: I typed your exact conf class definition, it works

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your method in the good way, so maybe you are not importing the module.

Check which file is loaded as `a.py` in `b.py`:

```
import a
print a.__file__
```

This will print which file is loaded.